# Cakephp3: $this->Auth->user('id') in AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.1

I got stuck at a certain problem with the use of $this->Auth->user('id') in AppController. It returns following Error:
Error: Call to a member function user() on null

Now what I want to do:
I want to force everybody to get a proper profile. So I created the function forceprofile() in AppController. I ask this function to be Executed in AppControllers beforefilter-function. So it will be executed every time. When there is no profile, the user will be redirected from the forceprofile-function into a form, where he can save his profile.

In the very first code line of this forceprofile-function, directly after some comments, I take the UserID into a variable:

```
$userid = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

This is where the Error occurs.

Than I wanted to check out what happened there, I replaced the line by

```
debug($this->Auth->user('id')); die;
```

The result was:

> int(1)

So actually I am getting a very proper result there.

The Stack of the original fault didn't provide any useful informations, it just prints [internal function] without any context or code... And it prints the BaseErrorHandler.

Anyone any idea, why debug() returns a proper result and asking the id to be assigned to a variable doesn't?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I continued debugging. For whatever reason, it seems, that the function forceprofile is called more than once. So it fails on the second execution. I think I need help figuring out, why and from where its called 2x.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the Problem myself now.

The function was called multiple times, because of loading multiple Controllers, doing callbacks, using Cells or whatever. I moved calling to this forceprofile function it to AppController::initialize(). Solved it.

Still it remains unclear for me, why executing the same code double (even if unintentionally) does not bring the same variables for usage.